# Endless sound in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, audio

I've got a problem with background music in game. It stops when I switch from main menu scene to game scene, but doesn't stop when game scene switches to gameOver scene. Also music overlaps when I choose replay (switch back from gameOver scene to game scene).
To play music I use AVAudioPlayer. ([player stop], [player play] etc :) )
What seems to be the problem here and how do I make music play continuously?

Comment: How this help me? I have this string in my code, and what? Please tell more information.

Comment: Please post the code where you start the background music.

Comment: @TheisEgeberg in GameScene, (in initWithSize) ' NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"mp3"]];
 player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
  player.numberOfLoops = -1;
  [player play];' and in another scenes I use this.

Comment: You could simply stop it when you switch scenes or replay. I agree it is strange it doesn't stop by itself.

Comment: @TheisEgeberg thank you. Yes, I do this in my "GameOver method", but music stop itself in 2 of 5 transition... Are You sure that music must stop only manually? (I apologize for mistakes in grammar:( )

Comment: I'm thinking that the player should get garbage collected and stopped when the scene is transitioned. What you're describing sounds very weird indeed.

Comment: @TheisEgeberg ok, thank you. But little more question: problem in automatically stop music or in "endless" music?

Comment: @user3684723 Post your code by editing you answer so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Ray Wenderlich's Audio Library, which can be found here:
https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/tree/master/SKTUtils

You just need SKTAudio.h & .m
But the other libraries are very nice as well

To start Music: 
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] playBackgroundMusic:@"bgMusic.mp3"];
To Pause: 
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance] pauseBackgroundMusic];

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you should have a separate method for setting up your sounds and then playing them in a another method.

First, setup your properties:

```
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *gameOverMusic;
```

In the initWithSize:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

      ...Your other code goes here

      [self setUpSounds];
 }
```

Then declare your method to setup the music:

```
 -(void) setupSounds {

  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"mp3"]]; 
  player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil]; 
  // -1 creates an infinite loop
  player.numberOfLoops = -1; 
 //Not [player play];
 [player prepareToPlay];

  NSURL *gameOverURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"GameOver" withExtension:@"mp3"];
  self.gameOverMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:gameOverURL error:nil];
  // 1 only plays once
  self.gameOverMusic.numberOfLoops = 1;
  [self.gameOverMusic prepareToPlay];
}
```

Play the background music:

```
 - (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

     [self.backgroundMusic play];
 }
```

And a separate method for the GameOver screen:

```
- (void) performGameOver {

  ...Your other code here

 // This stops the background music and plays gameOverMusic so they won't clash
  [self.backgroundMusic stop];
  [self.gameOverMusic play];
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted. It's working code in a production app.